# Why are new MediaStore files empty?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I'm trying to upgrade my app to use use scoped storage.  (Yes, I should have
done this a year ago.)  The old version writes to a File in a directory
relative to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().  The new version
writes to a uri from MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri().  My code has no
problem creating files in the mediastore destination directory, but the
files are empty.

My code is below.  I'm compiling under targetSdkVersion 29.  I've set it up
so I can compare the old version and the new version by setting
useMediaStore to either true or false.  Both versions call the same doSave()
routine.

doSave starts an asynchronous process to write the files, display a
progress bar, and report the result.  At the working end of the process
OutputStream.write is called, and we keep track of the number of bytes
written.  After the entire file is written, we call OutputStream.close(), and
report the number of bytes written.

When userMediaStore is false, fileName evaluates to
/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/mySoundFile.mp3 and the file gets created with the
expected length.  When useMediaStore is true, uri evaluates to
content://media/external_primary/audio/media/112, which turns out to be the
same as /Music.  The file is created but it is empty.  doSave() runs the
same in either case, and reports same number of bytes written.

The curious thing about it is that occasionally the MediaStore version works
correctly.  Then I change something and it stops working, and putting the
code back to where it was doesn't restore the function.

```
public static boolean useMediaStore = true;
public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton )
{
    try
    {
        String fileName = "mySoundFile.mp3";
        if ( useMediaStore )
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put( MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName );
            values.put( MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg" );
            Uri audioCollection = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29 ?
                MediaStore.Audio.Media .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
                : MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Uri uri = Utils.getContentResolver().insert( audioCollection, values );
            OutputStream stream = Utils.getContentResolver().openOutputStream( uri );
            doSave( getActivity(), stream );
        }
        else
        {
            File outputDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyApp" );
            if ( outputDir != null && ( outputDir.exists() || outputDir.mkdirs() ) )
            {
                File outputFile = new File( outputDir, fileName );
                OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream( outputFile );
                doSave( getActivity(), stream );
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        Log.i( "MyApp", "save failed" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use IS_PENDING twice.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by blackapps, the solution is to add IS_PENDING to the ContentValues.
The code that now works correctly is:

```
private static Uri contentUri = null;
public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton )
{
    try
    {
        String fileName = "mySoundFile.mp3";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put( MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName );
        values.put( MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg" );
        values.put( MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1 );
        Uri audioCollection = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29 ?
            MediaStore.Audio.Media .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
            : MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        contentUri = Utils.getContentResolver().insert( audioCollection, values );
        OutputStream stream = Utils.getContentResolver().openOutputStream( contentUri );
        doSave( getActivity(), stream );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        Log.i( "MyApp", "save failed" );
    }
}
protected void onPostExecute( Boolean success ) // part of the ASyncTask that does the saving
{
    if ( success )
    {
        ContentValues details = new ContentValues();
        details.put( MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0 );
        Utils.getContentResolver().update( contentUri, details, null, null );
    }
}
```

Comment: You only used IS_PENDING once. With value 0. But you were advised to use it twice. The first time with value 1. Thats missing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  My answer has been edited.